# Sitecore 8.1 A/B testing: How can I change the section position when I am performing testing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, ab-testing, sitecore8.1, abtest

I am working on the Sitecore A/B testing and I would like to test my A version with my product section on the top, while in B version, my whole product section is on the bottom?

I have tried to figure it out in the Sitecore Jetstream demo site first (see the diagram in below). I want to move the whole bottom section upwards in my version B, while version A keep as it is. However, I cannot do so but only able to change the component within a section.

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of Experience Optimization multivar, A/B tests in Sitecore, the component test and the page test. In your case which kind of test you need depends on the jet stream demo possibilities. With the page test you can test to a new page as long as it uses the same template. The component test is just for one component.

Create a new page where you move the hole section, and use a Sitecore page test.
(If it is not possible to move the section, first change the template to make it possible)

See [Create and Run Page Tests](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing__reporting/experience_optimization__content_testing/setting_up_tests/create_and_run_page_tests)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another quick question that I just discovered, my developer just discovered that when we go into Sitecore "Experience Editor", and then point to any components, there is no A/B testing button appear on the screen. Do you know what happen? And how we can change? Thanks!

Comment: Possible your in CMS-only mode no xDB, Experience Database,  which is required for content testing.